# Exception raised during rendering: View android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar not created with the right context

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-support-library

I'm receiving this error message in the Android Preview Designer as "Rendering Problems". I'm using API 22 to render and migrating to the new API support v4:22.1+ and v7:22.1+.

`Rendering Problems
Exception raised during rendering: View android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar not created with the right context`

[image: Rendering Problems]

Scenario:

- Using Android Studio v1.2RC
- Render API v22 (changing to 21 or 19 does not solve it)
- Migrating ActivityBarActivity to AppCompatActivity
- Compile section:

  `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.+'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.+'`
- Toolbar

  `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
  android:elevation="4dp"
  app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
  app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
  />`

Comment: Do you really need to rely on the IDE? Learn the XML and you can still build the UI yourself.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using your IDE to the fullest. The OP never said they built the UI, visually, with the IDE. More than likely, they were just trying to use the preview feature and that happens to be the fastest way to flesh out XML for the UI, in most cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error was caused because I had to remove in the Toolbar layout, the "app" section and change 'app:' by 'android:'.

Remove:

`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Replace:

`app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"`

For:

`android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"`

Comment: Thanks I've been seeing this problem for weeks and got tired of switching the Preview's theme to get around it. This worked, perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

> I solved this problem by Downgrading API level from 22,21 to 20  as shows
>   in below image

[image]